EventBus post multi on fragment when srceen rotated
I make an Android app with the following functions: When opening the app, create a viewpager(VP) and add 3 rooms(3 fragments) to the VP. Each room adds 1 fragment (same deviceFragment) but different TAG and name. Each fragment will have 3 buttons placed in the RecyclerView. I use EventBus to receive click events on each button click.
My problem is that when I open the app for the first time, the app runs perfectly without any errors, but if I rotate the screen, when the app resumes, pressing the button will generate 2 DEVICE_CLICK events. If you rotate the screen again, it will generate 3 events and continue to increase. I want when I rotate the screen, the app will re-initialize and not generate multiple DEVICE_CLICK events.
Please help
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ....

    vpAdapter = new deviceVPAdapter(this);
    vpAdapter.addFragment(new deviceFragment("Living_room", "0"));
        vpAdapter.addFragment(new deviceFragment("Working_room", "1"));
        vpAdapter.addFragment(new deviceFragment("Bath_room", "2"));
    vpDevice.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        vpDevice.setSaveEnabled(false);    
        vpDevice.setSaveFromParentEnabled(false);
        vpDevice.setAdapter(vpAdapter);
}

//viewPagerAdapter
public class deviceVPAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> listFrag;

    public deviceVPAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
            super(fragmentActivity);
            this.listFrag = new ArrayList<>();
        }

    @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
            return listFrag.get(position);
        }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fm){
            listFrag.add(fm);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            if(listFrag != null) return listFrag.size();
            return 0;
        }

    @Override
        public boolean containsItem(long itemId) {
            return super.containsItem(itemId);
        }

    @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return listFrag.get(position).hashCode();
        }
}

public class deviceFragment extends Fragment {
    public String TAG;
        private String pageName;

    public deviceFragment(String pName, String pIndex){
            TAG = pIndex;
            pageName = pName;
        }

    @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(...){
        ...
        
        List<deviceInfo> listDevice = new ArrayList();
        listDevice.add(new deviceInfo("sw 0");
        listDevice.add(new deviceInfo("sw 1");
        listDevice.add(new deviceInfo("sw 2");
        dAdapter = new deviceAdapter(listDevice);
        rcvDevice.setAdapter(dAdapter);
    }

    ....

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
        public void onEvents(variousData data){
        switch (data.getEventCode()){
            ...
            case DEVICE_CLICK:
            //this section called multi after rotate screen or os kill and resume
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            if(!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this))
                    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        }

    @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            if(EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this))
                    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        }
}

//device adapter (recycler view) on fragment
public class deviceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<deviceAdapter.deviceViewHolder>{
    List<deviceInfo> listDevice;
    
    public deviceAdapter(List<deviceInfo> listDev) {
            this.listDevice = listDev;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    .....

    public class deviceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public deviceViewHolder(@NonNull DeviceItemLayoutBinding dBinding) {
                    super(dBinding.getRoot());
                    this.devBinding = dBinding;
                    devBinding.btnDevice.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(new variousData(DEVICE_CLICK, null, getLayoutPosition(), listDevice.get(getLayoutPosition())));
            }
    }
}

I tried checking in deviceAdapter and it only generates 1 event/click so the problem due deviceFragment. I think case 1: the fragment being created many times, case 2 is due to Eventbus being registered many times (but I checked and found nothing wrong).
